# How to move a particular list item some pixels to the left using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As seen in the above image, I want the block with contents of "This is heading" to be positioned inline with the book icon.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="lessions">
   <ul>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="lession-heading"><a href="#">This is heading</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my css

```
.lession-heading{
    background: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 15px!important;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #000;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative margin on your list item, to bring it inline with the rest. `margin-left: -15px;`

```css
.lession-heading {
  background: #c1c1c1;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 15px!important;
  margin-left: -15px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="lessions">
  <ul>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="lession-heading"><a href="#">This is heading</a></li>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help. sir :)

Comment: @ShubhamSingh, if this solved your problem then please mark as solution.

Comment: @Kanstantsin I am new at stackoverflow, can't find any link to mark it as solution, only upvote button is there and I am not even allowed to upvote this

Comment: @ShubhamSingh No worries Shubham, you can see who posted the comment on the left (derloopkat in this case). You will be able to upvote people's answers once you have gained some reputation, 15 to be precise:)

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly, the books on the left are the bullet points for your list.

There are a few different things you can do to try fixing this:
1. You could change it from a list to a series of p tags, and leave the books as images you insert before any text:

```css
img {
  height: 20px;
}
#heading{
  background:#c1c1c1;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 15px!important;
  list-style-type:none;
  max-width:140px;
}
```

```html
  <p>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://thebookman.org/bookwebsite.jpg"> Chapter One </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#"> <img src="http://thebookman.org/bookwebsite.jpg">Chapter Two </a>
  </p>
  <p id="heading">This is the heading</li>
  <p>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://thebookman.org/bookwebsite.jpg"> Chapter Three </a>
  </p>
```

2. You could put the list into a div container and give it a margin-left bringing it in-line with the header

```css
.lession-heading{
    background: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 15px!important;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #000;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div{
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lessions">
   <ul>
       <div><li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li></div>
       <li class="lession-heading"><a href="#">This is heading</a></li>
       <div><li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

3. You could give the header a negative margin forcing it farther left.

```css
.lession-heading{
    background: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 15px!important;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #000;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lessions">
   <ul>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="lession-heading"><a href="#">This is heading</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
       <li class="chapter"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```